# Adding namespace to root node in visual mapper

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, biztalk

I need to add a specific namespace to show up in the output on the root node, which is not declared anywhere else.

My map is made using the visual mapper, so no XSLT. Is it possible to accomplish this without the use of XSLT?

Comment: Do you mean other then the Target Namespace?

Comment: Yes, the target namespace should remain the same

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way it to use Imports > XSD Import and select a schema with the desired namespace. I'm assuming you don't actually have such a schema, and creating a dummy for this seems a bit hacky.

You can also do this:

- open the target schema in a text editor (like Notepad++)
- add the desired namespace in the schema root
- add an import to reference the namespace

E.g.:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="original-xmlns" xmlns:myprefix="my-namespace" targetNamespace=...
  <xs:import namespace="my-namespace" />
  ...
```

Note that you will lose this import if you change the Imports property in Visual Studio afterwards.